# Django rest setting the one to one relation creating an post method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am new to django,I have created the models with OnetoOne relationship , I have user table and i have onetoone relation with storyboard library table, the issue is when i am creating an storyboardlibraby object , i need to save the user objectin the onetoonefield , even after adding user object not able to save the storyboardlibrary to the database, if anybody can help on this please help me , i will add the code which I have written.

```
class StoryboardLibrary(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   data = JSONField(db_index=True)
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return "%s The Library" % self.name
```

**Serializer class**

```
class StoryboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = StoryboardLibrary
    fields = ('data','name','user')
```

**views post method**

```
def add_storyboard(request):
# validating for already existing data
if StoryboardLibrary.objects.filter(**request.data).exists():
    raise serializers.ValidationError('This data already exists')
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
request.data['user'] = user
storyboard = StoryboardSerializer(data=request.data)
print(storyboard)
if storyboard.is_valid():
    storyboard.save()
    return Response(storyboard.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

**After hitting the post api i am not able to save the data storyboardserializer is not valid hence it is executing the else block and returning the status 404 not found**

Answer (score 0):

So,
here you are filtering with the requested user, so

```
get_object_or_404
```

is not required because if request comes, there is a user and an id.

also request.data is immutable you can not change it. so you can not add(modify) your own user to the recieved data.

```
request.data['user'] = user
```

rather you can pass context to your serializer with

```
storyboard = StoryboardSerializer(data=request.data, context = {'request':request})
```

and save user in create serializer method or directly save user as -

```
storyboard.save(user=request.user.id)
```

Comment: if you use **storyboard.save(user=request.user.id)** your serialization validation will fail if your user is a required field, in serializer, you can get your request object and get user from that or only pass user as context